# $http requests are not being handled by request interceptor

Tags: angularjs

This seems like a simple case: I'm trying to add a request interceptor to add OAuth bearer tokens to $http requests using Angular 1.1.5.  Here's my interceptor:

```
app.factory('bearerTokenInterceptor', function($injector, $q) {
  /*
   * This interceptor is available for providers that use the header based
   * bearer token for authentication
   */
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      /*
       * We need to use $injector to get access to the Token provider within
       * the body of the ctor - lest we want circular references created
       * by providers that need to use the interceptor (and also need the
       * Token provider
       */
      var Token = $injector.get('Token');
      config.headers.get = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Token.get() };
      return config || $q.when(config);
    }
  };
});
```

and then

```
app.config(function(TokenProvider, YammerTokenVerifier, $httpProvider) {    
  TokenProvider.extendConfig({
    authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth',
    verifyFunc: YammerTokenVerifier
  });

  /*
   * Yammer uses a bearer token - in comes the BearerTokenInterceptor!
   */
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('bearerTokenInterceptor');
});
```

But when I actually then use $http

```
$http.get('https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(headers);
    console.log(config);
    deferred.reject(data);
  });
```

The request interceptor is not getting called.  I don't see anything I'm doing that is beyond what the Angular docs suggest.  What am I missing?

Comment: You should not be injecting the $injector and calling a get on it. Why not request `Token` directly instead of the `$injector` ?

Comment: The pattern in the library causes a circular reference when I do it the standard way.  This was the only way to break it.

Answer (score 4):

I tried your code and it's ok. You just need to ensure that you're actually using angular js. 1.1.5. Try this: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js

Because with previous versions, `$httpProvider.interceptors` is undefined and trying to call `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('bearerTokenInterceptor');` throws exception.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2eDS/)

**Update:**

If you register your factory in another module, you need to add a dependency to that module using a code like this:

```
 var app = angular.module('yourapp',['factoryModule']);
 app.config(function(TokenProvider, YammerTokenVerifier, $httpProvider) {    
    TokenProvider.extendConfig({
    authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth',
    verifyFunc: YammerTokenVerifier
  });

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('bearerTokenInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: Would it make a difference if the interceptor factory was registered in a different angular module from the module that configured it?

Comment: @Ryan Norris: yes, it is. In that case, you have to refer to the module that the interceptor factory was registered using a code like this: `var app = angular('yourapp',['factoryModule'])`